R: Confused over \r character replacement using gsub
I have lots of line fragments like this:
...lorem ipsumMYLINEBREAK01\r \r SURNAME, Name (LT)\r \r\nMYBREAK01lorem ipsum...
It comes from processing a large html file with rvest::html_text2(). Long story short - it is unwieldy to process the file by nodes using xml2 parser - it takes too much time. If I strip the text of HTML the text has certain regularities that can be exploited. For example I have already inserted placeholders MYBREAK01 and MYLINEBREAK01. I get a bit over my head when trying to get rid of unneeded \r and \n (carriage returns and linefeeds that may be interspersed with spaces - or at least they appear to be spaces).
I tried to put in %>% gsub() in the processing chain that should get rid of these characters, but I have problems matching and I do not quite know what I am doing wrong:
gsub("(MYLINEBREAK01)(\r|\r\n| |\n)+([a-zA-Z ()]+)(\r|\r\n| \n)+(MYBREAK01)","\\1\\3\\5",.)
but it does not appear to match what I want - string fragment stays unchanged. And (LT) type thing does not always appear in the field. My aim is to get MYLINEBREAK01SURNAME, Name (LT)MYBREAK01 string, of course - without (LT) if it is not there.
I understand that as SamR and margusl have suggested I should use PCRE and that IS very helpful. However, I have also a problem that the string exists interspersed within other text and I need to restrict these changes to the area between markers MYLINEBREAK01 and MYBREAK01. That is why I had those capture groups. Am I going in the right direction with them, or am I missing something obvious here?
Many thanks!
P.S. reason I am using rvest::html_text2 is because I am preparing data to be loaded into an access database that I made - it has some neat search and filter features that help in text analysis. So for one of the fields I am trying to preserve line breaks. In prepping text I put in 3 BREAKs and one LINEBREAK placeholders, then I replace actual remaining linebreaks with yet another placeholder 0mylinebreak0, read this into a dataframe, replace 0mylinebreak0 with \n using stringr and then save into a csv. Which access then reads happily and I have a database of some 5k records that i can use further. Sounds cumbersome but beats manual going through the data.

does gsub('\\v', '', x, perl = TRUE) work for you?

Now the question has answers, I think it would be better to revert it and ask another question specifying a different problem, rather than editing to make the answers invalid

Hi SamR - I never meant to say answers are invalid. I asked the question trying to learn and I think I did not describe my situation well enough.

update to address question update:
str_replace_all() with lookbehind/lookahead in the regex and with function for replacement.
library(stringr)

s_ <- "...lorem \n ipsumMYLINEBREAK01\r \r SURNAME, Name (LT)\r \r\nMYBREAK01lorem \n ipsum..."
s_ <- str_c(s_, s_)
str_view(s_)
#> [1] │ ...lorem 
#>     │  ipsumMYLINEBREAK01{\r} {\r} SURNAME, Name (LT){\r} {\r}
#>     │ MYBREAK01lorem 
#>     │  ipsum......lorem 
#>     │  ipsumMYLINEBREAK01{\r} {\r} SURNAME, Name (LT){\r} {\r}
#>     │ MYBREAK01lorem 
#>     │  ipsum...

# minimum number of whitespace and non-whitespace characters between 
# positive lookbehind and lookahead patterns, 
# match gets first passed though str_squish() and then is used for replacement
s_2 <- str_replace_all(s_, "(?<=MYLINEBREAK01)[\\s\\S]*?(?=MYBREAK01)", str_squish)
str_view(s_2)
#> [1] │ ...lorem 
#>     │  ipsumMYLINEBREAK01SURNAME, Name (LT)MYBREAK01lorem 
#>     │  ipsum......lorem 
#>     │  ipsumMYLINEBREAK01SURNAME, Name (LT)MYBREAK01lorem 
#>     │  ipsum...


inital answer:
Sounds like a job for stringr::str_squish(), which is basically a fancy name for gsub("\\s+", " ", s_) |> trimws().
s_ <- "MYLINEBREAK01\r \r SURNAME, Name (LT)\r \r\nMYBREAK01"
stringr::str_squish(s_)
#> [1] "MYLINEBREAK01 SURNAME, Name (LT) MYBREAK01"

# which is basically 
gsub("\\s+", " ", s_) |> trimws()
#> [1] "MYLINEBREAK01 SURNAME, Name (LT) MYBREAK01"

rvest note: you might be after html_text() (sans-2) here, and approaching this problem through rvest with a combination of CSS selectors and/or XPath (and perhaps some xml2 tricks for some corner cases) would probably simplify your task.

Thanks, this works very well and I learned a few things about using str_replace_all(,,). I imagine that if you use capture groups in the match parameter, then you can refer to them in the replacement via "\\1" etc, just like in gsub()?

Interesting scenario, but  I'm afraid you can't refer to capture groups in a replacement function, from ?str_replace : replacement /../ "Alternatively, supply a function, which will be called once for each match (from right to left) and its return value will be used to replace the match."

Thanks, interestingly enough, it actually works: s_ <- "...lorem ipsumMYLINEBREAK01 SURNAME, Name (LT) 0 MYBREAK01lorem ipsum..." and then s_ %>% str_replace_all(., "(?<=MYLINEBREAK01).*(SURNAME).*(Name).*(?=MYBREAK01)", " \\2 \\1 works") gives "...lorem ipsumMYLINEBREAK01 Name SURNAME worksMYBREAK01lorem ipsum..."

Yes, this is expected. I somehow thought your question was about using a function as a 3rd str_replace_all() parameter. Lookbehind/lookahead in regex works with gsub() too.

Putting aside for a moment that you every time you parse html with regex it summons tainted souls into the realm of the living,
I think this is a good time for the PCRE \v. As the docs state:

\v matches any character considered vertical whitespace; this includes the platform's carriage return and line feed characters (newline) plus several other characters, all listed in the table below.

x <- "MYLINEBREAK01\r \r SURNAME, Name (LT)\r \r\nMYBREAK01"
gsub("\\v", "", x, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "MYLINEBREAK01  SURNAME, Name (LT) MYBREAK01"

It looks like you then want to do something weird with the spacing. We can use a negative lookbehind to remove all spaces unless they're preceded by a comma. As you've said you're not entirely sure they are spaces, I've used the PCRE \h:

\h matches any character considered horizontal whitespace; this includes the platform's space and tab characters and several others

gsub("\\v", "", x, perl = TRUE) |>
    gsub("(?<!,)\\h", "", x = _, perl = TRUE)

# [1] "MYLINEBREAK01SURNAME, Name(LT)MYBREAK01"

\h and \v will match the following characters that look like spaces. Most are not matched by \s in R (although they should be according to the PCRE spec):
0x0009        CHARACTER TABULATION   h s
0x000a              LINE FEED (LF)    vs
0x000b             LINE TABULATION    vs  [1]
0x000c              FORM FEED (FF)    vs
0x000d        CARRIAGE RETURN (CR)    vs
0x0020                       SPACE   h s
0x0085             NEXT LINE (NEL)    vs  [2]
0x00a0              NO-BREAK SPACE   h s  [2]
0x1680            OGHAM SPACE MARK   h s
0x2000                     EN QUAD   h s
0x2001                     EM QUAD   h s
0x2002                    EN SPACE   h s
0x2003                    EM SPACE   h s
0x2004          THREE-PER-EM SPACE   h s
0x2005           FOUR-PER-EM SPACE   h s
0x2006            SIX-PER-EM SPACE   h s
0x2007                FIGURE SPACE   h s
0x2008           PUNCTUATION SPACE   h s
0x2009                  THIN SPACE   h s
0x200a                  HAIR SPACE   h s
0x2028              LINE SEPARATOR    vs
0x2029         PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR    vs
0x202f       NARROW NO-BREAK SPACE   h s
0x205f   MEDIUM MATHEMATICAL SPACE   h s
0x3000           IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE   h s

For more see the PCRE docs.

Great, thanks I will test it. I used html_text2 to get rid of html before regexps precisely for the reason as to not summon unholy spirits

I updated my question explaining why I tried to employ capture groups, because the string is embedded in text that I do not want to change. Could you, please, look at this, maybe there is a way how to change that string without affecting other text?

Many thanks, great explanation and great answer. Apologies for not being very precise in my question initially, I should have said the main problem was how to deal with strings that are embedded in the text
